# Custom ToolStripItem

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I need to add a set of custom `ToolStripItem` (containing the additional property `formReference`) to a `ToolStripPanel` but they won't appear for some reason.

Code for adding the items:

```
foreach (Form form in Application.OpenForms)
if (form.Name != "MainForm")
{
    myToolStripItem mtsi = new myToolStripItem(form.Text, null, open_form);
    mtsi.formReference = form;
    tspTaskBar.Items.Add(mtsi);
}
```

myToolStripItem:

```
public class myToolStripItem : ToolStripItem
{
    public object formReference { get; set; }

    public myToolStripItem(string text, System.Drawing.Image image, EventHandler onClick)
        : base(text,image,onClick) { }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);
    }
}
```

Can you please point me to what I'm doing wrong? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem might be that `ToolStripPanel` is a panel for `ToolStrip`s and a `ToolStrip` is the actual place where you put `ToolStripItems`.  Try putting a `ToolStrip` inside your `ToolStripPanel` and putting your custom `ToolStripItem` into that `ToolStrip`.

Comment: i'm sorry, i said toolStripPanel but what i have is a ToolStrip (tspTaskBar is a ToolStrip, not a toolStripPanel). The tspTaskBar.Items.Add() method accepts a ToolStripItem as an argument so i'm pretty sure you add ToolStripItems to the Items collection.

Answer (score 2):

Deriving from `ToolStripMenuItem` instead of `ToolStripItem` solved it