# Extends ToolStripItem class in Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms

I would like to add my own class to `ToolStripMenuItem` object in windows forms.

According to this question: [Custom ToolStripItem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4316738/custom-toolstripitem) I tried this:

```cs
using System.Windows.Forms;
// ...
public class CultureItem : ToolStripItem
{
    public new string Text { get; set; }
    public new string Name { get; set; }
    public CultureInfo CultureInfo { get; set; }
}
// ...
public partial class View : Form
{
    public View()
    {
        var item = new CultureItem
        {
            Text = "Italy", Name = "IT", CultureInfo = new CultureInfo("it-IT")
        };
        languageToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.Add(item);
    }
}
```

and

```cs
using System.Windows.Forms;
// ...
public class CultureItem : ToolStripMenuItem
{
    public new string Text { get; set; }
    public new string Name { get; set; }
    public CultureInfo CultureInfo { get; set; }
}
// ...
public partial class View : Form
{
    public View()
    {
        var item = new CultureItem
        {
            Text = "Italy", Name = "IT", CultureInfo = new CultureInfo("it-IT")
        };
        languageToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.Add(item);
    }
}
```

Using code above I do not get any errors but `ToolStripMenuItem` show one value but with no text.

Comment: Add the Constructors you think you need to initialize your ToolStripItems and call `base()` passing the expected standard values (the `Text` and `Name`, for example).

Comment: It should look something like this: [ToolStripLabel not updated with application settings using PropertyBinding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65580860/7444103) -- That extends ToolStripLabel, which derives from ToolStripItem. It also adds the custom ToolStripItem to the ToolStripItems selector.

Comment: Why do you create `new` properties for `Text` and `Name`? Just remove them from your `CultureItem` class.  The base class has both properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use:

```
class CultureItem : System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem
{
     public CultureInfo CultureInfo { get; set; }
}
```

The `Name` and `Text` members will be there.